# Trigger on Task refuses to fire when using Time-Based workflow

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

When an opportunity closes as closed/won I have a time-based workflow that creates a series of task records with due dates in the future and a status of "open".  I can see when my opportunity is closed/won that the time-based workflow shows up in the queue, after a few minutes I then see the new task records created on the Opportunity

I am trying to run some code in a before trigger on the Task object, but the trigger never seems to fire.  I turned on debug logs on for my user and the automated process user but my simple debug statements do not show for some reason.

Is there something specific or unique to working with triggers and time-based workflows that maybe I am missing?

Here is the trigger code which doesn't have really anything yet, but I can't even get the debug statement to show.

```
trigger TaskAction on Task (before insert) {

    List<Task> TestTaskList = new List<Task>();

     System.debug('Testing Task Trigger ----------------------------');

    
}
```

Comment: debug log on for the `Process automation settings | default workflow user` (which may be diff than you or the automated process user)?

Comment: What happens if you manually create a task, does the trigger fire?